# how can I set variables in wildfly standalone.xml

Tags: xml, jboss, wildfly

I have to type same ip address more than 6times in standalone.xml

then I wonder is there any way to set this ip as variable so I just have to change once.

is there any way to set a variable in standalone.xml without using env.sh?

I've tried making a tag like this and failed to start wildfly

```xml
<variable name="ip_addr" value="192.168.0.24"/>  
...skip...
<interface name="public">
    <inet-address values="${jboss.bind.address:ip_addr}"/>
</interface>
...skip till the end...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not `variable` option to store values in the configuration. The expression pattern is `${system.property.name:default_value}`. You could keep the default of `${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}` and add a system property for `jboss.bind.address` with the value of your IP address. With CLI it would look like:

```
/system-property=jboss.bind.address:add(value=192.168.0.24)
```

You can also use the web console to add the system property.

Your other option is to set the system property in the `JAVA_OPTS` in the `standlone.conf` for Linux based operating systems or `standalone.conf.bat` for Windows.

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Djboss.bind.address=192.168.0.24 $JAVA_OPTS"
```

Comment: thanks a lot! for me, it looks better to add a system property for jboss.bind.address rather than setting in the java_opts.  thx again for you suggestion and clearing that there is no variable option in configuration